# Get the number pressed from a dial-pad

Tags: android

I want to get the number pressed from the dialpad during an ongoing call

scenario:

1. Say person A calls person B.
2. During the call, person A opens dialpad and presses a number,say
   number 1

So How can I get the dialed no?

Answer (score 3):

> get the number pressed from the dialpad during an ongoing call :

To get Number from outgoing call you will need to register an `BroadcastReceiver` for `PHONE_STATE` Action. inside `onReceive` method you will retrieve as:

```
String outgoingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER)
```

For more help you can see following tutorial :

[Manipulating Incoming & Outgoing Calls Tutorial For Android](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/manipulating-incoming-ougoing-calls-tutorial-for-android/)

Comment: Actually i don't need the dialed number.

Comment: To be more clear the person A has already dialed a number and person B has answered the incoming call. So now both person A and B are having a conversation. Now the person A opens his dial-pad and has pressed a number say 1 from the dial-pad. Now i want to capture that number and launch my activity. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Can any suggest me an android application for same. thanks in advance